# how to move entire existing excel range to one row down using interop in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, interop

how to move entire existing excel range to one row down using interop in C#?

I need to add a header in 1st row of existing excel which has only data.I want to move the entire rangel one setup down programatically in C#.

I saw moving a cell stuff,but moving the entrire range was not clear.
could you please help me with it.

Comment: Is C# interop with Excel a must? Otherwise there is a _really_ good open source library called ClosedXML  (http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) that works like a charm especially in server (headless) environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree if you are running on a server, CloseXML is a better solution, but if you want to go the interop way:

Here is the code to add a row and shift the existing data down by one row.

```
// Inserts a new row at the beginning of the sheet
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range a1 = sheet.get_Range( "A1", Type.Missing );
a1.EntireRow.Insert(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, 
                    Type.Missing );
```

After you have inserted your new row at the top, you can add the headers to the cells.
I assume you know how to open and access the sheets.

Comment: @nune : hey, if i have 2 header columns in the excel at row 1 and at row 3..then if i start inserting data from 2nd row, how can i make the 3rd row, which has the headercolumns get pushed down for each insertion at the top...
Thanks...